# drools serialization of global vars

Tags: serialization, global-variables, drools

I use this code to fully serialize/deserialize drools (5.4.0.CR1) statefull session objects:

```
private static void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out, KnowledgeBase knowledgeBase, StatefulKnowledgeSession session) throws IOException
{
    // out.defaultWriteObject();
    DroolsObjectOutputStream droolsOut = new DroolsObjectOutputStream(out);
    droolsOut.writeObject(knowledgeBase);
    Marshaller marshaller = createSerializableMarshaller(knowledgeBase);
    marshaller.marshall(droolsOut, session);
}

private static Marshaller createSerializableMarshaller(KnowledgeBase knowledgeBase)
{
    ObjectMarshallingStrategyAcceptor acceptor = MarshallerFactory.newClassFilterAcceptor(new String[] { "*.*" });
    ObjectMarshallingStrategy strategy = MarshallerFactory.newSerializeMarshallingStrategy(acceptor);
    Marshaller marshaller = MarshallerFactory.newMarshaller(knowledgeBase, new ObjectMarshallingStrategy[] { strategy });
    return marshaller;
}

private static StatefulKnowledgeSession readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    // in.defaultReadObject();
    DroolsObjectInputStream droolsIn = new DroolsObjectInputStream(in);
    KnowledgeBase knowledgeBase = (KnowledgeBase) droolsIn.readObject();
    Marshaller marshaller = createSerializableMarshaller(knowledgeBase);
    StatefulKnowledgeSession statefulSession = marshaller.unmarshall(droolsIn);

    return statefulSession;
}
```

It works correctly, the only problem is that the global variables of the session are lost.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I fixed this after the release of CR1. Try a current snapshot or CR2 when it is released.